# calling a method wont change the value unless from within the method itself

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to figure out my mistake.

I am working on `Account` class in C++, where there are a few methods like `credit()`, `debit()`, etc.
I wrote a `transfer()` method and the problem I get is that it takes "money" out of account `a1` but does not credit the `a2`. However if I print it within the method itself in account.cpp it does show the correct result, while in main the balance stays the same.

Can you see my mistake? Something to do with reference, pointers, etc?
Here is the main:

```
a1.println(); 
a2.println();
cout<< "Valid parameter " << endl;
cout<< a1.transfer(a2, 13) << endl;
a1.println();
a2.println();
```

Here is what it prints:

```
(Account(65,140))
(Account(130,100))
Valid parameter 
1
(Account(65,127))
(Account(130,100))
```

Here is the definition of methods:

```
    // withdraw money from account
    bool Account::debit(int amount){
    if (amount>=0 && balance>=amount) {
        balance=balance-amount; // new balance
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


// deposit money
bool Account::credit(int amount){
    if (amount>=0) {
        balance=balance+amount; // new balance
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Account::transfer(Account other, int amount){
    if (amount>=0 && balance>=amount) {
        debit(amount);
        other.credit(amount);
        //other.println();// prints corect amount
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are passing the other `Account` by value. The balance gets changed OK, but on a different *instance* of the account, meaning that the copy gets modified, while the original stays intact.

Change your code to passing `Account` by reference to make it work.

```
bool Account::transfer(Account& other, int amount)
//                            ^
//                           HERE
```

Comment: great, thanks, it works. So from what i understand when i called a1.transfer(a2, 13) it made a copy of a2 and did not change the original a2? Therefore using a reference showed it to the correct location, and as a result set the value in correct location? Still getting used to it.

Comment: @AuRis You are correct, passing by value makes and changes a copy, while passing by reference lets you change the item "in place".

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass "other" by reference

```
 bool Account::transfer(Account& other, int amount){
```